# Push Major doesn't work while upgrading users

Tags: managed-package, package, push-upgrade

I was planning to upgrade my users from version 3.4 to 3.5 and 3.6 using major push upgrades. I am able to go to "Setup > Create > Packages > Versions > Push Upgrades > Schedule Push Upgrade"
But the only options I get is to push minor versions, ie from 3.4.1 to 3.4.2 or 3.4.X.

I did create a case with Salesforce support and according to support, my org is activated with Push Major capability.

1. How do I use Push major versions? Is there some other screen I should be looking at?
2. My developer Org is Summer '13, is it something visible only in Winter '13 or doesn't this matter?